# How to do registration successful, copy the contents of one column of the table to the other?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to do registration successful, copy the contents of one column of the table to the other? For example successful registration, automatic copy `users => id` for `users => url`. I can not realize it. Please help me to create a function!!!

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)");
}
```

[image]

[image]

```
<?php
include 'core/init.php';

if (empty($_POST) === false) {
    $required_fields = array('username', 'password', 'password_again', 'first_name', 'email');
    foreach($_POST as $key=>$value) {
        if (empty($value) && in_array($key, $required_fields) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Fill in all fields to continue registration.</div>';
                break 1;
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors) === true) {
        if (user_exists($_POST['username']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Unfortunately, the user name <b>' . $_POST['username'] . '</b> It is already in use.</div>';
        }
        if (preg_match("/\\s/", $_POST['username']) == true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Your user name should not contain spaces.</div>';
        }
        if (strlen($_POST['password']) < 6) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Your password must be at least 6 characters.</div>';
        }
        if ($_POST['password'] !== $_POST['password_again']) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Your passwords do not match.</div>';
        }
        if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">A valid email address is required.</div>';
        }
        if (email_exists($_POST['email']) === true) {
            $errors[] = '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">Unfortunately, e-mail address <b>' . $_POST['email'] . '</b> It is already in use.</div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php
if (empty($_POST) === false && empty($errors) === true) {
    $register_data = array(
        'username'   => $_POST['username'],
        'password'   => $_POST['password'],
        'first_name' => $_POST['first_name'],
        'last_name'  => $_POST['last_name'],
        'email'      => $_POST['email']
    );

    register_user($register_data);
    echo '<div id="result_x"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div><div id="error">You have successfully registered!</div>';
} else if (empty($errors) === false) {
    echo output_errors($errors);
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Why are you 'copying' anything anywhere?

Comment: @Strawberry, I need to site.com/url. For example, when the automatic registration shall url site.com/id1. And if users want to change such site.com/alex. How can realizirovat? Is there another solution?

Comment: Perhaps use google's auto translate feature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After Insert query...  fetch the last insert id and update the row

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
mysqli_query($con,$insert);
$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
$update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
 mysqli_query($con,$update );
```