# I can not find an error in php (It all starts here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393024/)

Tags: php

I can not find an error in php. Sometimes such a error:

> Warning: array_walk() expects parameter 2 to be a valid callback,
>   function 'array_sanitize' not found or invalid function name in
>   Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 3
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 10
>
> Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null
>   given in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given
>   in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 13

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
    mysqli_query($con,$update );
}
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Full code:

**init.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(0);

require 'database/connect.php';
require 'functions/languages.php';
require 'functions/general.php';
require 'functions/users.php';

if (logged_in() === true) {
    $session_id = $_SESSION['id'];
    $user_data = user_data($session_id, 'id', 'username', 'password', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email');
}

$errors = array();
?>
```

**users.php**
Old code:

> ```
> function register_user($register_data) {
>     array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
>     $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);
>
>     $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
>     $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';
>
>     mysql_query("INSERT INTO `users` ($fields) VALUES ($data)"); 
> }
> ```

```
<?php
function register_user($register_data) {
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
    mysqli_query($con,$update );
}

function user_count() {
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `active` = 1"), 0);
}

function user_data($id) {
    $data = array();
    $id = (int)$id;

    $func_num_args = func_num_args();
    $func_get_args = func_get_args();

    if ($func_num_args > 1) {
        unset($func_get_args[0]);

        $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', $func_get_args) . '`';
        $data = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT $fields FROM `users` WHERE `id` = $id"));

        return $data;
    }
}

function logged_in() {
    return (isset($_SESSION['id'])) ? true : false;
}

function user_exists($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
function email_exists($email) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function user_active($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `active` = 1"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}

function id_from_username($username) {
    $username = sanitize($username);
    return mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `id` FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username'"), 0, 'id');
}

function login($username, $password) {
    $id = id_from_username($username);

    $username = sanitize($username);
    $password = md5($password);

    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' AND `password` = '$password'"), 0) == 1) ? $id : false;
}
?>
```

**general.php**

```
<?php
function protect_page() {
    if (logged_in() === false) {
        header('Location: protected.php');
    }
}

function aray_sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}

function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

function output_errors($errors) {
    return '<ul><li>' . implode('</li><li>', $errors) . '</li></ul>';
}
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
<?php
$host="Localhost";
$db="social";
$user="social";
$password="social";
$connect_error = 'Sorry, we\'re experiencing connection problems.';
mysql_connect($host, $user, $password) or die($connect_error);
mysql_select_db($db) or die($connect_error);
?>
```

Comment: These are warnings though not errors.

Comment: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) is one issue; `$con` is not defined inside your register_user() function

Comment: Where is the array_sanitize function???

Comment: $con is to be made global inside the function register_user

Comment: @Vickrant, `function aray_sanitize(&$item) {
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item);
}

function sanitize($data) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}`

Comment: Please post the code how You initialize $con.

Comment: Looks like you're playing pick-and-mix with database extensions.... MySQL !== MySQLi.... use MySQLi consistently, and you'll have a lot less problems.... learn to use bind variables, and you don't need to escape your values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
function register_user($register_data) {
    global $con;
    array_walk($register_data, 'array_sanitize');
    $register_data['password'] = md5($register_data['password']);

    $fields = '`' . implode('`, `', array_keys($register_data)) . '`';
    $data = '\'' . implode('\', \'', $register_data) . '\'';

    $insert = "INSERT INTO users($fields) VALUES ($data) ";
    mysqli_query($con,$insert);
    $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($con);
    $update = "UPDATE users SET url = '".$last_id."' WHERE id = ".$last_id." ";
    mysqli_query($con,$update );  
}
function aray_sanitize(&$item) { 
    $item = mysql_real_escape_string($item); 
}
```

Comment: That fixes the mysqli errors, but not the one about array_sanitize.

Comment: Redefining the function will get rid of the warnings, but it won't sanitize the data.

Comment: Sometimes this error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 11

Warning: mysqli_insert_id() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in Z:\home\site.kz\www\core\functions\users.php on line 14

Comment: From where you get $con is it a valid connection? Please paste the code how $con gets initialized